# Si 2 elementos HTML van seguidos, seleccionar el primero con CSS

Tags: css

Tengo esta estructura de HTML:

```
<br>
<br>
<blockquote>
```

Quiero seleccionar con CSS el elemento `<br>` que va justo antes del `<blockquote>` sólo cuando van uno detrás de otro.

Estoy probando con:

```
br + blockquote ~ br {//estilos}
```

Pero no me funciona. Si fuese al revés no habría problema porque me serviría con un `blockquote + br`. Estoy siguiendo las reglas de [selectores de CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dice @Ale, pero si lo haces de esa forma y lo tienes varias veces, sólo tomará el último de ellos. Tienes que utilizar clases para diferenciarlos. Si por ejemplo lo tienes 2 veces, pues sería algo así:

```
HTML:

<br class="primero">
<br class="primero">
<blockquote>


<br class="segundo">
<br class="segundo">
<blockquote>

CSS:

br.primero:last-of-type{
}

br.segundo:last-of-type{
}
```

Otra forma es utilizando una clase concreta para diferenciar a los últimos:

```
<br>
<br class="ultimo">
<blockquote>

<br>
<br class="ultimo">
<blockquote>

<br>
<br class="ultimo">
<blockquote>

<br>
<br class="ultimo">
<blockquote>

br.ultimo{
}
```

Comment: Si claro, yo supuse que tenia solo la estructura que mostró, en el caso de tenerlo varias veces tu respuesta esta genial.

Comment: Pues estoy en un problema, porque no tienen clases, todos son iguales.

Comment: Pues asignale una clase, qué problema hay?

Comment: @PabloGonzález no puedo acceder a los br, me los pone automáticamente al pintar en pantalla la información de la base de datos. De hecho si hago un `str_replace("<br>","", comentario)` no me hace absolutamente nada. Por eso tengo que solucionarlo con CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Con esa estructura que estas mostrando podrías usar `br:last-of-type` y estarias seleccionando el ultimo de los br

Tambien podrias ponerle un id al br y listo